# Getting author tests to be created and run for dzil test

Tags: perl, testing, plugins, module, dist-zilla

I am trying to use several Dist::Zilla plugins to generate and run author tests. The only problem is that they are generated by `dzil build` and not run with `dzil test`. As an example, here are some lines in my dist.ini:

```
[Test::Compile]     ; Create t/00-compile.t
[Test::UnusedVars]  ; Create xt/unused-vars.t
[RunExtraTests]     ; run the xt/ tests when dzil test is run.
```

Running `dzil test` however, only runs one of the created test files- `00-compile.t`. `unused-vars.t` isn't even created until I run `dzil build`. In order to test all of the author tests created like this, I need to first run `dzil build`, cd into the new directory, then run `dzil test`. Then, when something fails, I have to work with the original copy, not the copy created by the build command. Rinse and repeat.

Is there a way to get the author tests to be generated at build time so that I can run them with `dzil test` without changing directories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dzil test --release` is what you're looking for.
And I would also strongly recommend you to try [Dist::Zilla::PluginBundle::TestingMania](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aPluginBundle%3a%3aTestingMania)

Comment: Indeed. I was confused about having author set to yes and release set to no by default. Thanks!